# Hover nav wont stay open to click on

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, hover

So here is the actual page, [remsen](http://www.remsen.philmitch.com/), and here is what the code looks like.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".nav_drop_menu1").hide();
            $(".nav_button1").show();

        $('.nav_button1').hover(function(){
        $(".nav_drop_menu1").slideToggle();
        });

            $(".nav_drop_menu2").hide();
            $(".nav_button2").show();

        $('.nav_button2').hover(function(){
        $(".nav_drop_menu2").slideToggle();
        });
    });
    </script>


<br>



    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="nav_button1">Home</li>
        <li class="nav_button2">Services</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
            <div class="nav_drop_menu1">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Current Brews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_drop_menu2">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Current Brews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

What I want is for the drop menu to stay open long enough to actually click it, or at least while it's being hovered over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I deleted all of the JQuery. I added all of the effects with css.

First of all, you don't need to hide the sub menus, you can just define them in the css as `max-height:0px`. Usually you use `display:none` but display cannot be animated with transition. Also `height:auto` is sort of glitchy.

Second: You can produce all of the effects with pure css thus evade including the jquery library, since it's actually pretty heavy.

Third: I moved the `<div>`s inside the respective `<li>`s to make them easier to control.

I added a few other classes and etc, but tried to keep the maximum of your initial code intact. But, as you can see in the demo bellow, you can delete a lot.

I think those are all of the changes on the css I made:

```
.nav_button:hover>.submenu>ul{
    max-height: 30px;
}

.submenu{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.submenu ul{
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.3s linear;
    max-height: 0px;
}
```

and

```
.nav_drop_menu1, .nav_drop_menu2, .nav_button1, .nav_button2{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

became:

```
.nav_button1, .nav_button2{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kMy2c/1/) of the result. Keep in mind that both the animation function and speed of the animation can be easily altered.

I hope, this is the result you expected.